# Problem running Express app over HTTPS on aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, single-page-application

I have an ExpressJS backend and I want to run over https on aws (so I don't get 'mixed type content' error when trying to connect with my frontend which runs over https), it's running great using http but when using https it doesn't work.
I asked this question before and I got answers like 'use nginx', 'use load balancer', unfortunately I don't know much about this stuff as I'm not very experienced with all aws variations and options, are there any tutorials I can follow step by step ? or any easy way to serve my backend over https without complexity?

Comment: So your backend is running on a single EC2 instance? Is it custom setup instance, or for example, one from Elastic Beanstaslk?

Comment: I uploaded my zip file to elastic beanstalk and it automatically created t2 micro instance, only works for http but not for https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> any easy way to serve my backend over https without complexity?

The easiest way (don't confused with the cheapest way) is to change your EB environment to load-balanced one. You can do this in EB console's configuration settings.

This change will create Application Load Balancer for your app, and place it in-front of your instance. Once ALB is running you can follow this AWS guide:

- [How can I configure HTTPS for my Elastic Beanstalk environment?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-https-configuration/)

In the above, only section `Terminate HTTPS on the load balancer` would be relevant.

Depending on the nature of your application, is it fully dynamic, or more on static side, you could also consider using [Using Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudfront.html), instead of using ALB. CloudFront could be also be easily setup to use HTTPS between clients and CloudFront, but the issue is that traffic between CloudFront and your EB instance would go over the internet unencrypted (HTTP). Obviously, you could make it HTTPS, but this requires further changes and configurations which does not fall into category of "easy ways".

Comment: if I use the first option which is Load balancer, any idea about how much extra I will have to pay (currently using t2 micro instance)

Comment: If you are using t2.micro, I guess you are on free tier. ALB is covered by [free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&all-free-tier.q=load&all-free-tier.q_operator=AND). So would have to check if you are not over the free-tier limits.

Comment: thanks a lot man, I will give it a try and let you know how it went.

Comment: @OmarZahir You still can install SSL cert on classic load balancer. Shoudn't be much difference.

Comment: I tried the first option (ALB), the problem is the load balancer type is 'Classic' not 'Apllication', can't change it even after changing it in the instance it doesn't change on the elastic beanstalk application.
I even tried going with the classic load balancer but it asked for a certificate that I have to get from certificate manager, will the ALB ask for a certificate too ?, can't I do the whole thing with my self signed certificate?

Comment: also in the certificate manager it asks for a domain name, I only have the long url provided by aws as I only use it as a backend, how can I handle this ?

Comment: will the ALB ask for a certificate too ? Yes, off course. You can get free SSL cert using AWS ACM. You need your own domain for SSL cert. You have to buy one, if you don't have any.

Comment: can I provide the domain for my front-end? I bought it from hostgator

Comment: @OmarZahir Yes. Any domain which you control, as you will have to verify this, using CNAME records once you create the SSL cert in ACM.